# upgrading a dependency in MongoDB driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, nuget

We use MongoDB driver 2.12.1 which is the latest version.
A vulnerability has been discovered in one of the dependencies of this driver. SharpCompress 0.23.
I need to upgrade this to SharpCompress 0.29.

The CSharp project I am working with makes no explicit mention of the SharpCompress library.
Any idea how to go about updating it?

Thanks,
Tauqir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest driver version is `2.13.1`. However, the latest SharpCompress version is buggy (see issues in the github), so there is no way other than waiting for fix.

Comment: Fortunately veracode changed it's mind and now considers SharpCOmpress 0.21 onwards to not have medium flaws. I can afford to wait.